# How to draw a flow arrow using networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Is there any method to draw a flow arrow directed to a given node using networkx, like this photo, given a node?

[image: example]

All I have found are methods to draw arrows on edges between the graph nodes.

Comment: I don't think it's built in to networkx, but the image is a matplotlib plot, so it should be possible to do using the matplotlib commands.

Comment: do you have an idea how to draw it in a existing networkx graph using matplotlib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a first pass at it.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.karate_club_graph()

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

ax = plt.axes()
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, ax=ax, with_labels=True)

x,y = pos[0]
dx = 2
dy = 2

ax.arrow(x-dx-0.02, y-dy-0.02, dx, dy,head_width=0.05, length_includes_head=True )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ,that was so helpful